# Managing session state with html::mason

Tags: perl, mod-perl, mason

I'm using `HTML::Mason` with `Apache2 mod_perl2` for a project and am unsure what's a good way to manage session state easily.

Please don't say use Catalyst. I normally do, but not on this occasion.

Comment: how about using Dancer?  :)

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this for a long time I finally have a working solution:

This is using mysql to store session data so that no matter which front-end server you hit, you will get the same session data.

You will need a db with a table called sessions made with this:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (id char(32), length int, a_session text);
```

This is in MySession.pm in my INC path.

```
package MySession;

use DBI();
use Apache::Session::MySQL;
use Apache2::Cookie;

sub start_session($){
  my ($r) = @_;

  my $cookie_name = 'mysite-session';
  my $cookie_domain = '.mysite.com';

  my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=db;host=host.com";
  my $dbuser = 'admin';
  my $dbpass = 'password';


  my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, {'RaiseError' => 1});

  my $session_cookie = Apache2::Cookie->fetch($r)->{$cookie_name};

  my %cookie_hash;
  if(defined($session_cookie)){
    %cookie_hash = $session_cookie->value();
  } 

  tie my %session, 'Apache::Session::MySQL', $cookie_hash{SessionID}, {
    Handle     => $dbh,
    LockHandle => $dbh
  };

  my $cookie = Apache2::Cookie->new($r,
  -name => $cookie_name,
  -domain => $cookie_domain,
  -value => {SessionID => $session{_session_id}}
  );

  $cookie->bake($r);

  return \%session;
}

1;
```

Then on any page you wish to use/modify session data:

```
% use MySession;
% my $session = MySession::start_session($r);
% $session->{variable} = "Wow, I have a cookie";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found the answer in

```
MasonX::Request::WithApacheSession
```